# I can't solve "Use of undeclared type 'SphereNode'" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to make a simple measurement application using Swift's ARKit.

I ran a demo project to find a good example.

But I could not use 'SphereNode'.

The process of creating the first application using Swift is challenging.

I hope you can understand because English is not my first language.

My full source is below.

Thank you.

P.S. My System version is 'OSX ver. 10.14', 'xCode ver. 10.0' the latest at 2018. 09. 27

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Reference : https://virtualrealitypop.com/ios-11-tutorial-how-to-measure-objects-with-arkit-743d2ec78afc.
//

import UIKit

//Import ARKit and SceneKit frameworks
import ARKit
import SceneKit
//Conform our ViewController to ARSCNViewDelegate protocol.
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    var nodes: [SphereNode] = []

    //Create a lazy sceneView variable to store ARSCNView instance
    lazy var sceneView: ARSCNView = {
        let view = ARSCNView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()
    //Create a label to display status information.
    lazy var infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title1)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Add sceneView to our host view
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
        //Add the label to host view
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        //
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //2
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)
        //3
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .featurePoint)
        if let result = hitTestResults.first {
            //4
            let position = SCNVector3.positionFrom(matrix: result.worldTransform)
            //5
            let sphere = SphereNode(position: position)
            //6
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
            let lastNode = nodes.last
            nodes.append(sphere)
            if lastNode != nil {
                //7
                let distance = lastNode!.position.distance(to: sphere.position)
                infoLabel.text = String(format: "Distance: %.2f meters", distance)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //Resize sceneView
        sceneView.frame = view.bounds
        //Update the label position
        infoLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: view.bounds.width, height: 64)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //Start ARKit session
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) {
        //Implement protocol function to display status changes
        var status = "Loading..."
        switch camera.trackingState {
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.notAvailable:
            status = "Not available"
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.limited(_):
            status = "Analyzing..."
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.normal:
            status = "Ready"
        }
        infoLabel.text = status
    }

}

extension SCNVector3 {
    func distance(to destination: SCNVector3) -> CGFloat {
        let dx = destination.x - x
        let dy = destination.y - y
        let dz = destination.z - z
        return CGFloat(sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz))
    }

    static func positionFrom(matrix: matrix_float4x4) -> SCNVector3 {
        let column = matrix.columns.3
        return SCNVector3(column.x, column.y, column.z)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `SphereNode` is defined (presumably in another file)?

Comment: I did not think I had to do anything extra because I got it from Git. I'm an idiot who can not think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple. You are making reference to an SCNNode `Subclass` called `SphereNode`, yet this isn't included in your project.

A quick look at the source code reference provided in your question points to the following `GitHub Repositor`y: [AR Measure Demo](https://github.com/kravik/ArMeasureDemo)

If you look in the source code their is a class called `SphereNode.swift`:

```
//
//  SphereNode.swift
//  ArMeasureDemo
//
//  Created by Igor K on 8/17/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Igor K. All rights reserved.
//
import SceneKit

class SphereNode: SCNNode {
    init(position: SCNVector3) {
        super.init()
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.005)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        sphereGeometry.materials = [material]
        self.geometry = sphereGeometry
        self.position = position
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

As such if you make your current file something like so, the error will go away:

```
import UIKit

class SphereNode: SCNNode {
    init(position: SCNVector3) {
        super.init()
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.005)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        sphereGeometry.materials = [material]
        self.geometry = sphereGeometry
        self.position = position
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//Import ARKit and SceneKit frameworks
import ARKit
import SceneKit
//Conform our ViewController to ARSCNViewDelegate protocol.
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    var nodes: [SphereNode] = []

    //Create a lazy sceneView variable to store ARSCNView instance
    lazy var sceneView: ARSCNView = {
        let view = ARSCNView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()
    //Create a label to display status information.
    lazy var infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title1)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Add sceneView to our host view
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
        //Add the label to host view
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        //
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //2
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)
        //3
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .featurePoint)
        if let result = hitTestResults.first {
            //4
            let position = SCNVector3.positionFrom(matrix: result.worldTransform)
            //5
            let sphere = SphereNode(position: position)
            //6
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
            let lastNode = nodes.last
            nodes.append(sphere)
            if lastNode != nil {
                //7
                let distance = lastNode!.position.distance(to: sphere.position)
                infoLabel.text = String(format: "Distance: %.2f meters", distance)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //Resize sceneView
        sceneView.frame = view.bounds
        //Update the label position
        infoLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: view.bounds.width, height: 64)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //Start ARKit session
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) {
        //Implement protocol function to display status changes
        var status = "Loading..."
        switch camera.trackingState {
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.notAvailable:
            status = "Not available"
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.limited(_):
            status = "Analyzing..."
        case ARCamera.TrackingState.normal:
            status = "Ready"
        }
        infoLabel.text = status
    }

}

extension SCNVector3 {
    func distance(to destination: SCNVector3) -> CGFloat {
        let dx = destination.x - x
        let dy = destination.y - y
        let dz = destination.z - z
        return CGFloat(sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz))
    }

    static func positionFrom(matrix: matrix_float4x4) -> SCNVector3 {
        let column = matrix.columns.3
        return SCNVector3(column.x, column.y, column.z)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. When I first dealt with Swift I thought it was basically a defined object.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the code that defines `SphereNode`.

You could replace that line with something like this:

```
let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
sphere.position = position
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't running.